# Is there a way to hot reload QML when using the new CMake API for modules?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I have seen many outdated answers about this question, but they do not take the new [CMake QML Modules API](https://www.qt.io/blog/whats-new-for-qml-modules-in-6.5) into consideration.
In short, you declare a qml module in CMake with some QML and/or C++ or asset files and you get a generated plugin to be linked against by your application and a generated qmldir file in the **build directory**. All files are added to the resource system. I already tried a shortcut to reload the qml in the engine using `QQmlApplication::loadFromModule("Main", "Main")` (see link, this is new in 6.5 and does not seem to rely on qrc only).

Is there any chance to hot reload QML files within a running application with the given setup?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you need to do the following changes:

1. Following your example of `QQmlApplication::loadFromModule` usage, create a `Main` directory and put a `Main.qml` file into it.
2. Create a `Main/qmldir` file with the contents like

```
module Main
Main 1.0 Main.qml
```

You can also copy the `qmldir` file from the build directory, where the files generated by `qt_add_qml_module` are located.

3. In C++ code, add a call to `QQmlEngine::addImportPath("/path/to/parent/dir/of/Main")`, before calling `QQmlApplication::loadFromModule("Main", "Main")`.

As long as you add your module to the import path (even if it's conditionally decided at runtime), the `loadFromModule` function will prefer to load `Main.qml` from the disk, and not via `.qrc`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I recommend QmlPreview:

Build->QmlPreview